# How to access key-value Lookup through the API in GoodData?

Tags: api, gooddata

In GoodData's ETL tool there's a key-value store that one can use for keeping some kind of state between ETL runs: http://developer.gooddata.com/cloudconnect/manual/lookup-table-functions-ctl2.html

Is there a way how to set / read these values through the REST API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something called project metadata. It holds metadata on a per project level. It is what you can see if you go to Project explorer in CloudConnect and look at customer properties.

The data can be read like this

```
GET /gdc/projects/<projectName>/dataload/metadata
```

You can read only particular key

```
GET /gdc/projects/<projectName>/dataload/metadata/<key>
```

And update an existing key

```
PUT /gdc/projects/<projectName>/dataload/metadata/<key>
```

Also delete

```
DELETE /gdc/projects/<projectName>/dataload/metadata/<key>
```

Or create a new on

```
POST /gdc/projects/<projectName>/dataload/metadata/ {"metadataItem" : {"key" : "some_key", "val" : "some_val"}}
```

Another way is to use GoodData ruby SDK (https://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-ruby/)

```
client = GoodData.connect('username', 'pass')
project = client.projects('project_id')
project.metadata

metadata.inspect
```

You can also set the metadata liek this

```
project.set_metadata('key', 'val')
```